# Can fluentbit listen for syslogs on multiple ports, transform logs depending on the port, and send to different destinations?

Tags: logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I'm new to fluentbit and my org is restructuring our log ingestion nodes. The ingestion nodes take in syslogs from multiple platforms. Each platform has 100s of individual devices and this continues to grow, which is why separating via port numbers (rather than some sort of list of devices on the ingestion node) is the current idea.

If fluentbit is running on the ingestion node, would it be possible for:

1. Each platform sends syslogs on a different TCP port to the ingestion node
2. The ingestion node runs fluentbit, and listens for syslogs on the various port numbers used by the platforms
3. Depending on the port number, fluentbit tags the syslogs with a particular string, and sends the logs to a particular destination

I did a search for fluentbit and multiple ports numbers but didn't see anything come up. Would this be possible? If fluentbit can't accomplish this, could I use fluentd?

Answer (score 0):

Fluentbit supports INPUTS from syslog using the [Syslog Input Plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/syslog)

> Syslog input plugins allows to collect Syslog messages through a Unix socket server (UDP or TCP) or over the network using TCP or UDP.

This Plugin Supports the following option(s) as of v2.1

| Configuration | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Mode | Defines transport protocol mode: unix_udp (UDP over Unix socket), unix_tcp (TCP over Unix socket), tcp or udp |
| Listen | If Mode is set to tcp or udp, specify the network interface to bind. |
| Port | If Mode is set to tcp or udp, specify the TCP port to listen for incoming connections. |

You can setup a configuration that has multiple syslog input plugins, each listening on a different port and each setting the `Tag` to what you want.

On the output side, you can then forward each of the `tags` to different output plugins using the `match` option.

See [Routing](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/concepts/data-pipeline/router) on how tag and match works